# Mostrar videos de uma pasta vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Galera eu estava usando o seguinte código para mostrar diversas imagens em um listview como se fosse uma biblioteca.

```
For Each arquivos In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.png", "*.jpg")

        Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(arquivos)
            img = Image.FromStream(str)
            imagem.Images.Add(img)
        End Using

        ListView1.LargeImageList = imagem
        ListView1.Items.Add(arquivos, contador)
        contador += 1
```

Eu gostaria de saber se posso fazer algo parecido, mas com video. Mostrando um frame do video e clicando para abrir o video.

Ex: Filmes e tv da Microsoft e YouTube.

Comment: 1) Lista os arquivos da pasta, 2) gera um Miniatura (Thumbnail) de cada um dos arquivos de vídeo. 3) Exibe as Miniaturas

Comment: Essa é a parte que eu estou com dificuldade. Como eu gero as miniaturas a partir dos videos?

Comment: Eu pensei em usar o ffmpeg: ffmpeg.exe -i video_file.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 output.png

Comment: O Azure possui este serviço: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-video-summarization

Comment: Por favor não poderia dar um exemplo de um código?

Comment: var process = Process.Start(...);
process.WaitForExit(); https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148162/194717

Comment: Poderia dar o exemplo de um código de como pegar um frame de um video para usar como miniatura usando a linguagem que eu usei?